# Using mobile design elements for standard web pages?

Tags: website-design, layout, mobile

I'm a big fan of minimalist design and really like the efficiency and layout of sites and apps designed for mobile devices ([Tripit.com](http://tripit.com) comes to mind). I often find myself trying to incorporate similar design and layout techniques (headerless datagrids, simple icons without descriptive text, etc.) for standard web sites and web based apps I'm working on, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Which mobile design and layout techniques have you effectively used in standard web design?

Comment: This question seems a bit vague as the techniques you could use would, in part, be determined by the requirements of your design project.  I don't believe you can generalize an appropriate answer for this question.

Comment: @jameswanless Fair enough. I've edited my question a bit. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luke Wroblewski is a big proponent of 'design for mobile first' which is akin to what you are talking about:

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1117

In general, designing for mobile forces you to focus on the user more so than we're often allowed to elsewhere. So it's a great place to start.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Many thanks!